# How to disable child form controls?

Tags: c#

I have a login which have admin and user rights.

If admin- i can access all the forms and controls.
--OK

If user- i can only access limited forms and controls.
I have Mdi parent and other forms.

--NOT OK

I can only disable toolstrip menu on MDI parent but i need to disable controls on the other childforms also.

like butttons/textboxes etch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this:

- When opening/loading the control, pass the login rights to the child control and have the OnLoad method set the visibility
- Add a public method on your child form to hide the control.  The parent could then call this method
- Make the controls public and access them directly from the parent (i.e. `childForm.ControlToHide.Visible = false`).  Gets the job done but is not recommended

Lots of other ways too, these are simply the "easy" ones.